# How to structure MySQL database to show link records in PHP under a Parent directory type structure?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save some Website Links into a Database table and then print them to screen with PHP.

The part I need help with is that some of the Link records will act as `parent` records and then `child` records will be under it;s parent.

The goal is to generate something like the image below but pulling the link records from a MySQL Database with PHP.

I am not sure how best to structure the database for this.  AS a start I have added a column called `parent` in which I figured that each link record could have the `ID` of the `Parent` record.

A Parent record will act as a Folder/Directory.

[image]

My Databse structure as of right now...

```
id
title
description
url
permission
notes
active
sort_order
parent (will have the ID number of the parent folder/link of this link)
```

Based on this, how could I pull the records with PHP and make sure that the links stay under the parent link records like in the image?

Does my Database need to be changed to do this?

Comment: this resembles the employee-manager problem, imagine you want to list a manager and the employees under him like your image

Comment: a join of the table and the table itself maybe ?

Comment: My idea so far...looping over the records, a Parent record could have it;s own ID set as it;s Parent value.  `if($id === $parent)` then it is a Parent record, then maybe assign matching records that have a Parent value that are the same as the new parent record just set, saving them to an array or something...I guess I need to get my hands dirty and try some test

Comment: @jasondavis: your method will work, but ordering indexed data in MySQL is faster than looping over a record set and saving data in an array done by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you database is perfect, you'll only have to work on how retrieve those informations in PHP.

I can give you a little hint, you'll have to use a recursive function, like this one :

```
function arrayLinks($parent) {
  // Your SQL query for retrieving all links with $parent
  $query = query("SELECT * FROM link WHERE parent = ".$parent);

  // For each row, just return another arrayLinks function
  $arrayLinks = array();
  foreach($query as $row) {
    $arrayLinks[] = array(
       'row' => $row,
       'child' => arrayLinks($row['id'])
    );
  }
  return $arrayLinks;
}

$arrayLinks = arrayLinks(0);
```

This will give you an array like this one :

```
[{
  row: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Link 1'
  },
  child: [{
   row: {
     id: 3,
     title: 'Link 1-1'
   },
   child: []
  }, {
   row: {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Link 1-2'
   }
  }]
}, {
  row: {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Link 2'
  },
  child: []
}]
```

In this exemple, you have those links :

- Link 1

  - Link 1-1
  - Link 1-2
- Link 2

Comment: Great thanks!  I know this is basic 101 stuff, i've just never actually had to do this before!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the parent has a smaller id than any of its children and that the default value of the parent column is null, could you order them this way:

```
(select ...., concat(concat(id,'_'),id) as parent_id from website_links where parent IS NULL
union
select  ...., concat(concat(parent,'_'),id) as parent_id from website_links where parent IS NOT NULL) 
order by parent_id;
```